# Load item cost from an inventory table

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have an Inventory Sheet that contains a bunch of data about products I have for sale. I have a sheet for each month where I load in my individual sales. In order to calculate my cost of sales, I enter my product cost for each sale manually. I would like a formula to load the cost automatically, using the product name as a search term.

```
 Inventory Item  |  Cost                 Sold Item  |  Sale Price  |  Cost
 Product 1       |  2.99                 Product 3  |  16.99       |   X 
 Product 2       |  4.99                 Product 3  |  14.57       |   X 
 Product 3       |  6.99                 Product 1  |  7.99        |   X
```

So basically I am looking to "solve for X".

In addition to this, the product name on the two tables are actually different lengths. For example, one item on my Inventory Table may be "This is a very, very long product name that goes on and on for up to 120 characters", and on my products sold table it will be truncated at the first 40 characters of the product name. So in the above formula, it should only search for the first 40 characters of the product name.

Due to the complicated nature of this, I haven't been able to search for a sufficient solution, since I don't really know exactly where to start to quickly explain it.

### UPDATE:

The product names of my Inventory List, and the product names of my items sold aren't matching. I thought I could just search for the left-most 40 characters, but this is not the case.

Here is a sample of products I have in my Inventory List:

---

Ford Focus 2000 thru 2007 (Haynes Repair Manual) by Haynes, Max

Franklin Brass D2408PC Futura, Bath Hardware Accessory, Tissue Paper Holder, ...

Fuji HQ T-120 Recordable VHS Cassette Tapes ( 12 pack ) (Discontinued by Manu...

Fundamentals of Three Dimensional Descriptive Geometry [Paperback] by Slaby, ...

GE Lighting 40184 Energy Smart 55-Watt 2-D Compact Fluorescent Bulb, 250-Watt...

Get Set for School: Readiness & Writing Pre-K Teacher's Guide (Handwriting Wi...

Get the Edge: A 7-Day Program To Transform Your Life [Audiobook] [Box set] by...

Gift Basket Wrap Bag - 2 Pack - 22" x 30" - Clear [Kitchen]

GOLDEN GATE EDITION 100 PIECE PUZZLE [Toy]

Granite Ware 0722 Stainless Steel Deluxe Food Mill, 2-Quart [Kitchen]

Guess Who's Coming, Jesse Bear [Paperback] by Carlstrom, Nancy White; Degen, ...

Guide to Culturally Competent Health Care (Purnell, Guide to Culturally Compe...

Guinness World Records 2002 [Illustrated] by Antonia Cunningham; Jackie Fresh...

Hawaii [Audio CD] High Llamas

And then here is a sample of the product names in my Sold list:

---

My Interactive Point-and-Play with Disne...

GE Lighting 40184 Energy Smart 55-Watt 2...

Crayola® Sidewalk Chalk Caddy with Chalk...

Crayola® Sidewalk Chalk Caddy with Chalk...

First Look and Find: Merry Christmas!

Sesame Street Point-and-Play and 10-Book...

Disney Mickey Mouse Board Game - Duck Du...

Nordic Ware Microwave Vegetable and Seaf...

SmartGames BACK 2 BACK

I have played around with searching for the left-most characters, minus 3. This did not work correctly. I have also switched the [range lookup] between TRUE and FALSE, but this has also not worked in a predictable way.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). Augment the *lookup_value* parameter with the [LEFT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-function-BE3191EA-D332-43E4-BAC3-810C97773A22).

[image: VLOOKUP_LEFT]

In the above example, `LEFT(E2, 9)` is used to truncate the *Sold Item* lookup into *Inventory Item*.

Comment: as allways, simple and clean :) *+1*

Comment: Thank you! I will experiment with this and get it to work.